# jquery 1.9.1 -- Origin ... is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

When I try to make a `getJSON` call, get an error:

`Origin ... is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

This script works with jQuery 1.4.2 but not with 1.9.1:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
var nyc = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%22hello%20kitty%22";

$.getJSON( nyc , function(data) {  
    $('.nyc').text("abcd"); 
});
```

Searching on this site, this is clearly a jQuery specific error.  Here is something to fiddle with: http://jsfiddle.net/mrcactu5/5yscM/2/

Comment: No, it's **not** a jQuery specific error. There are simply a lot of people here who use jQuery.

Comment: @MattBall I'd replace "here" with worldwide. `;)`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté with [the black sheep joke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_joke#Stereotypes_of_mathematicians) in mind, can you guess which one I am? `:P`

Comment: @MattBall heh, I've turned my brain's mathematical side off about 8 hours ago, though I see what you mean, I'll take the astronomer's role. `:P`

Comment: i hope you guys are right... actually I don't see what they change.

Comment: @ OP yes, if twitter's search isn't CORS-enabled (which it probably isn't), you get such an error due to Same Origin Policy. @MattBall I'd guess you're a mix of physicist with mathematician. `:P`